# com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating (check service name)

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-email-audit-api

I try to use [email audit api](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/) for my G suite. I connect with the admin of my domain.
This is my code:

```
package com.archivage.gmail;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.audit.AuditService;
import com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.audit.MailBoxDumpRequest;
import com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.audit.MailMonitor;
import com.google.gdata.data.DateTime;
import com.google.gdata.data.appsforyourdomain.generic.GenericEntry;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class HttpURLConnectionExample {


    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    // HTTP GET request


    // HTTP POST request
    public static void sendPost(String domain, String userId) throws Exception {

        String url = "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/mail/monitor/" + domain + "/" + userId;
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        System.out.println("testing url");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/atom+xml");
      // con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("destUserName","user");


        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
      //  wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);

      //  System.out.println(response.toString());

        File p12 = new File("/path/key.p12");

        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        String[] SCOPESArray = {"https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"};
        final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId("8888990087766.apps.googleusercontent.com")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12)
                .build();


        MailBoxDumpRequest mailboxDumpRequest = new MailBoxDumpRequest();
        mailboxDumpRequest.setBeginDate(new Date());
        mailboxDumpRequest.setEndDate(new Date());
        mailboxDumpRequest.setIncludeDeleted(true);
        mailboxDumpRequest.setSearchQuery("in:chat");
        mailboxDumpRequest.setPackageContent("FULL_MESSAGE");

        MailMonitor monitor = new MailMonitor();
        Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        endDate.set(2017, Calendar.AUGUST, 30, 23, 20);
        monitor.setEndDate(endDate.getTime());
        monitor.setChatMonitorLevel("HEADER_ONLY");
        monitor.setDestUserName("user@domain.pro");

        AuditService service = new AuditService("admin@domain.pro", "password", "domain.pro", "project-id");
        // GenericEntry entry = service.createMailMonitor("user@domain.pro", monitor);

        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        //System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result

        Calendar fromDate = Calendar.getInstance();

       // GenericEntry mailboxDumpEntry2 = service.retrieveMailboxDumpRequest("user@domain.pro", "10");
     //   String status = mailboxDumpEntry2.getProperty("status");


        fromDate.set(2017, Calendar.AUGUST, 30, 21, 0);
        List<GenericEntry> mailboxDumpRequestEntries = service.retrieveAllMailboxDumpRequests(fromDate.getTime());
        for (GenericEntry entry : mailboxDumpRequestEntries) {
            MailBoxDumpRequest request = new MailBoxDumpRequest(entry);
            String  status = request.getStatus();

            service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);

            GenericEntry dumpRequest = service.createMailboxDumpRequest(mailboxDumpRequest);


            System.out.println(dumpRequest.toString());

        }

    }
}






package com.archivage.gmail;



import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.BearerToken;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;

import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GmailApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GmailApplication.class, args);

        try {
            HttpURLConnectionExample.sendPost("doamin.pro","user@domain.pro");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

I got this Error in console:

> com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating (check service name)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:688)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:560)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:397)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:364)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:319)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:303)
>       at com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.audit.AuditService.(AuditService.java:77)
>       at com.archivage.gmail.HttpURLConnectionExample.sendPost(HttpURLConnectionExample.java:91)
>       at com.archivage.gmail.GmailApplication.main(GmailApplication.java:28)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I reformatted your question to make it more easily readable. You can use quotation blocks (with a leading '>') to display error messages.

Comment: Seems to me like you're having problems getting past the OAuth2 Java implementation. You can give the [Directory API Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/java) a try and adapt the OAuth2 Java code.

Comment: Hi Noogui i used  Directory API Java Quickstart and it work but if i used api email audit i have always this problem of invalid token :                                        <HTML>
   <HEAD>
       <TITLE>Token invalid - Invalid token: Unsupported token type 5</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
       <H1>Token invalid - Invalid token: Unsupported token type 5</H1>
       <H2>Error 401</H2>
   </BDY>
</HTML>7